# python passing \n as \x0a to bash command line

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, escaping

So I am trying to pass a command from python to command line as hex newline: **\x0a**
Which in python is also know as "**\n**"

what I'm trying to print through the command line is:

> check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_users -a "`echo -e "\x0a ls "` #" 4 4

I tried

```
import subprocess as sb
sb.check_call(["check_nrpe", \ # first argument
               "-H", host, # host
               "-c", "check_users", # wanted remote command
               "-a", # option
               "\"`echo -e", 
               "\"\\x0a", # <new line>, problem is that python changes this to \n 
               parameter,
               "\"` #\"", "4", "4"]])
```

**"\"\x0a"** # , problem is that python changes this to **\n** when passing the argument to the command line

So what i want to do is **\x0a** to be printed instead of **\n**

also i tried to encode

```
  "\n".encode("hex")
  which prints "0a"
```

Question is that how i tell python to pass the argument \x0a to the command line.

Comment: Your question isn't clear

Comment: Question is that how i tell python to pass the argument \x0a to the command line.

Comment: Have you try single quotes `'\x0a'` or more backslashes `"\\\\x0a"` or both ?

Comment: dont know about you, but when I am given `os.system("echo '\\x0a'")` its printing `\x0a` for me. I guess you just have to change " to '

Comment: It does send `\x0a`: ``-H -c check_users -a "`echo -e "\x0a "` #" 4 4
``. `check_nrpe` might be the one having a problem.

Comment: I would say, you are rather trying to make the `check_nrpe` call working. Is simple call from command line working for you? Your python call and sample bash call do differ.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(["echo", '\\x0a'])` also works!

Answer (score 0):

## Clarify your `check_nrpe` call

Assuming, you have Nagios installed (I have it and run Ubuntu)

```
cd /urs/lib/nagios/plugins
```

See, `check_nrpe` help

```
$ ./check_nrpe -h

NRPE Plugin for Nagios
Copyright (c) 1999-2008 Ethan Galstad (nagios@nagios.org)
Version: 2.12
Last Modified: 03-10-2008
License: GPL v2 with exemptions (-l for more info)
SSL/TLS Available: Anonymous DH Mode, OpenSSL 0.9.6 or higher required

Usage: check_nrpe -H <host> [-n] [-u] [-p <port>] [-t <timeout>] [-c <command>] [-a <arglist...>]

Options:
 -n         = Do no use SSL
 -u         = Make socket timeouts return an UNKNOWN state instead of CRITICAL
 <host>     = The address of the host running the NRPE daemon
 [port]     = The port on which the daemon is running (default=5666)
 [timeout]  = Number of seconds before connection times out (default=10)
 [command]  = The name of the command that the remote daemon should run
 [arglist]  = Optional arguments that should be passed to the command.  Multiple
              arguments should be separated by a space.  If provided, this must be
              the last option supplied on the command line.
 -h,--help    Print this short help.
 -l,--license Print licensing information.
 -n,--no-ssl  Do not initial an ssl handshake with the server, talk in plaintext.

Note:
This plugin requires that you have the NRPE daemon running on the remote host.
You must also have configured the daemon to associate a specific plugin command
with the [command] option you are specifying here.  Upon receipt of the
[command] argument, the NRPE daemon will run the appropriate plugin command and
send the plugin output and return code back to *this* plugin.  This allows you
to execute plugins on remote hosts and 'fake' the results to make Nagios think
the plugin is being run locally.
```

Review your sample call (I have corrected formatting which got lost in your original post, it was hiding backquotes):

```
$ check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_users -a "`echo -e "\x0a ls "` #" 4 4
```

It seems like you try to call `check_users` command and pass it some arguments. So the final call on remote (NRPE driven) machine would look like:

```
$ check_users "`echo -e "\x0a ls "` #" 4 4
```

Comparing it to what `check_users` proposes on help screen:

```
$ ./check_users -h
check_users v1.4.15 (nagios-plugins 1.4.15)
Copyright (c) 1999 Ethan Galstad
Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Nagios Plugin Development Team
        <nagiosplug-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>

This plugin checks the number of users currently logged in on the local
system and generates an error if the number exceeds the thresholds specified.


Usage:
check_users -w <users> -c <users>

Options:
 -h, --help
    Print detailed help screen
 -V, --version
    Print version information
 -w, --warning=INTEGER
    Set WARNING status if more than INTEGER users are logged in
 -c, --critical=INTEGER
    Set CRITICAL status if more than INTEGER users are logged in

Send email to nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net if you have questions
regarding use of this software. To submit patches or suggest improvements,
send email to nagiosplug-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
```

It is clear, your attempt to call `check_users` over `check_nrpe` is broken as `check_users` expects exactly four arguments and the call should look like (assuming you consider 4 users be both critical and warning level):

```
$ ./check_users -c 4 -w 4
```

So your final call of `check_nrpe` could look like:

```
$ check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_users -a -c 4 -w 4
```

Note, that if you are trying to pass dynamic values to critical and warning, you shall do that over Nagios variables and do not assume, it will be shaped by command line (which happens on your remote machine). Such a technique could work, but is rather tricky.

## Passing newline or other characters to command line calls

Another topic is, how to pass newlines or other special characters to commands from Python.

Here it is not so difficult, as you have a chance passing a list of arguments, which does not get interpreted by shell, but is directly passed to the command.

### Simple commandline script `bcmd.py`

Following script allows testing what parameters were passed into it from command line:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

### Test of calling commands from Python code

```
from subprocess import call

args = ["python", "bcmd.py"]
args.append("alfa")
args.append("be\nta")
args.append("""gama
        hama""")
args.append("omega\x0aOMEGA")
args.append("double-omega\x0adouble-OMEGA")
args.append("literaly\\x0aliteraly")

call(args)
```

Call it:

```
$ python callit.py 
['bcmd.py', 'alfa', 'be\nta', 'gama\n        hama', 'omega\nOMEGA', 'double-omega\ndouble-OMEGA', 'literaly\\x0aliteraly']
```

and learn from it.

## Conclusion:

- Python allows calling commands and passing arguments via list bypassing shell parsing rules.
- In your case, the real problem seem to be in use of `check_nrpe` rather then in passing in newlines.